# aws amplify ,amplify push, amplify pull

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, cloud, aws-amplify

please help with this error code, I wanted to push my react.js project to the cloud with "amplify push" after  I double-checked my configurations. and this error still persists when I do a amplify push or amplify pull

"Error downloading #current-cloud-backend.zip from deployment bucket: amplify-amplifylogin-dev-135835-deployment, the error is: The specified key does not exist."

Comment: run `amplify configure` and then try `amplify publish `

Comment: your env is corrupted. I would delete the project and pull it again

Comment: Try  removing the whole amplify file then  amplify pull to get the file